# visualizing and revising a large number of plots in for loop in r

Tags: r, plot

Here is the question where I have a number of plots and I want to revise them one by one visually at once pace.

```
xm <- matrix(runif(20000), ncol = 1000)

 for (i in 1:ncol(xm)){
    hist(xm[,i], col = i)
 }
```

This loop will make the plots so fast that I will have slit second to look (or not at all) in graphical device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There can be several way around:

(1) **look plots one by one - press return key to see next plot**

We can create a breaks and user can use return key to see next plot.

```
xm <- matrix(runif(20000), ncol = 1000)
for (i in 1:ncol(xm)){
    hist(xm[,i], col = i, main = paste(i))
    grDevices::devAskNewPage(ask = TRUE)
}
```

Note that default behavior in R is  `grDevices::devAskNewPage(ask = FALSE)`.

(2) **input plot number you want see from keyboard**

You  select which variable you want to plot, this way you can avoid chronological visualization of the plots, or else you can input the plot number(s) you want, in the order you want and click stop when you are done.

```
for (i in 1:ncol(xm)){ 
    i <- scan(nmax=1)
    hist(xm[,i], col = i, main = paste(i))
}
```

(3) **all plots in new windows**

If you would like to make a new plot each time, you can use:

```
for (i in 1:10){
    hist(xm[,i], col = i, main = paste(i))
    dev.new()
}
```

(4) **multiple plot in single window**

If you like to plot multiple plots in a single plot:

```
par(mfrow = c(5,2))
for (i in 1:10){
    hist(xm[,i], col = i, main = paste(i))
}
```

(5) **Pdf file with multiple plots in separate page**

Another way to save the files as PDF or other format:

The following will create output PDF will all figures in different page and then can scrolled down up.

```
pdf("outtrtt.pdf",width=7,height=5)
    for (i in 1:ncol(xm)){
        hist(xm[,i], col = i, main = paste(i))
    }
dev.off()
```

(6) **separate pdf files per plot**

Or if you want to create output as single PDF file per plot or other image file types this may do so. Please note that this may be different in mac and windows.

```
 for (i in 1:ncol(xm)){
     pdf(paste("var", i, ".pdf", sep = ""),width=7,height=5)
         hist(xm[,i], col = i, main = paste(i))
     dev.off()
 }
```

(7) **separate image files**

You can save as jpeg or other format of your choice

```
 for (i in 1:ncol(xm)){
     jpeg(paste("var", i, ".jpeg", sep = ""),width=700,height=500)
         hist(xm[,i], col = i, main = paste(i))
     dev.off()
 }
```

Other answers are welcome.

Comment: I would add to this already good answer the possibility to save all the plots in a PDF file (and then browse through them).

Comment: thanks your comments and other improvement are made.